# Finding the two most similar groups in 4-10 variables from 60 possible groups

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a data set of 200k observations of about 75 variables representing people in about 60 distinct jurisdictions. I am trying to figure out which jurisdictions are most similar to each other on the basis of say 4-10 different demographic variables (all continuous). Essentially, what I am trying to do is pick two jurisdictions that are as similar as possible in one but very different with regard to a specific variable (per-child funding in a specific grant). Once I figure out which districts are most similar, I can just check the pairs to see which are disparate in funding.

I checked [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26394/find-similar-observations-in-two-datasets), but it doesn't seem to apply.

How can I quantitatively determine just how similar two groups are? Bonus if there's a scikit-learn library that handles it...

Comment: Any single similarity score would be some sort of aggregation/comparison between the observation pairs.  scikit-learn has several [Pairwise metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html?highlight=pairwise#module-sklearn.metrics.pairwise).

Comment: Thanks @rickhg. Would pairwise options work if the districts do not contain the same number of observations?

Comment: I believe most, if not all, of the scikit-learn pairwise metrics require equal number of observations.